# My images wont scale down

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, scaling

Hey my images wont get smaller when I resize my screen. They just jump down below each other.

Can someone check my code and see whats wrong. I want the images to resize, so there will only be two besides each other on smaller screens.

Download link to code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VTnZ4FBmMUFUjoxrvue2ZFj98botja4c?usp=sharing

Link to webpage: http://lamp2.sdu.dk/~chmad17/Visit%20Kolding/

Comment: How can we check your code? There isn't any

Comment: cant you download it from my drive?

Comment: You should read up on Media Queries (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) , which is the appropriate way to change how the site looks on smaller devices. For future reference, it would be better to recreate your code in a snippet on SO - people are unlikely to want to download a file you've linked to.

Comment: Please consider adding your code to the question. Additionally try to narrow your code to a simpler example that can be used to replicate your problem

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your code but I assume you have some images next to each other. Give each image a percentage width which is representative of the space each one takes up.

**Note 1:** you will need to make them inline-block elements so you can control the width.

**Note 2:** Make sure there's a DIV containing them - as this will be a block element that is automatically 100% width.

```
<div>
  <img src="image1.jpg" style="width: 23%">
  <img src="image2.jpg" style="width: 52%">
  <img src="image3.jpg" style="width: 25%">
</div>
```

**Note 3:** The widths need to add up to less than or equal to 100%

**Note 4:** Add `font-size: 0px;` to the DIV to fix an issue where images adding up to 100% still wrap